# Retrieving attribute's domain using ArcIMS ActiveX Connector?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, image-service, arcims

I have an ArcIMS Image Service that's consuming data stored in an ArcSDE database (both v9.3.1).

Many of the layers have attribute columns that use coded value domains defined in the SDE database, and I'd like to be able to display the values defined in the domains.

Is it possible to retrieve the all values in the domain associated with an attribute column via an ArcXML request to the ActiveX connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.  At least, you couldn't before 9.3 (I haven't looked at 9.3).  Back in the day, we wrote some DB stored procs to get that data and then got the values via ADO.NET. Not sure if that would even work anymore.

I hate when someone answers a question with a "can't be done" answer, but in this case, you can't get those values with anything IMS offers, AFAIK. You'll have to go to the db, or an ArcObjects service for that.